# How to create a list of factors of a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, processing

I am trying to create a function that returns a list of factors for use elsewhere in my programme. However, the function I've created doesn't appear to return anything and I'm failing to understand why. If you can spot the mistake then I'd appreciate the help!

Please note: This is using a version of JavaScript in Processing 2.2.1, which I'm aware is very out of date!

```js
function Factors ()
  {
   var list_of_factors = new Array ();  
    for (int index = 0; index < number_of_balls; index++) {
        if (number_of_balls % index == 0) {
          append(list_of_factors, index);
        }  
      }
      return list_of_factors;
      println(list_of_factors);
    }
```

Comment: Well, I don't see the keyword `return` used anywhere in the function, so that's likely why it's not returning anything.

Comment: What language is this? `int` doesn't seem like valid JS code.

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure where to add the return, as it doesn't seem to be making any difference. Where should it go? Thanks.

Comment: It is JavaScript, just outdated!

Comment: https://processing.org/reference/int.html

Comment: Not sure what language this is. `int` `append` or `println` don't really sound like JavaScript.  Is this algorithm supposed to calculate prime factors or just enumerate all factors of a number? Either way, you don't need to iterate all the way up to `number_of_balls` but can stop at `sqrt(number_of_balls)`

Comment: Definitely JavaScript, just out of date version! All factors, but good tip thanks!

Comment: As nobody seems to know that version of js, it's quite hard to help. If `%` calculates the modulus, `append` adds a value to an array and `println` is capable of printing arrays, your algorithm should work. For your function to return the result to the caller you'd have to add `return list_of_factors` (or whatever the equivalent of return is in that dialect) as last statement of the function.

Comment: Ah sorry, for factors, of course, you have to iterate until `number_of_balls / 2`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Hopefully I'll work it out!

Comment: @TaviaLewis `int` has never been valid JavaScript. It was only *more invalid* for a while when it was a reserved keyword. But at that point in time, it only threw explicit errors if trying to use it as a keyword. Now `int` is no longer reserved but it throws errors just because it's syntactically invalid code. You've linked to the page of Processing which is a different programming language altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your there is no return value is because you are not `return`ing anything.

Try this out:

```js
function Factors (number_to_factor) {
    var list_of_factors = new Array ();  
    for (var index = 0; index < number_to_factor; index++) {
        if (number_of_balls % index == 0) {
          append(list_of_factors, index);
        }
    }
    return list_of_factors;
}
```

Notice the `return` statement at the end of the function? That is what causes the function to return a value.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but even using return, when I put the println statement afterwards, there still appears to be no output? Am I doing something else wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you put the `print` after the `return` it's not executed.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Where am I able to put print so I can see the list of values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function Factors() {
  var list_of_factors = new Array();
  for (let index = 0; index < number_of_balls; index++) {
    if (number_of_balls % index == 0) {
      list_of_factors.push(index);
    }
  }
  return list_of_factors;
}
```